# Exclude one file from password protection in .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I have the following code to protect files with password in `.htaccess`:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|css|js|php|swf|swz|xml|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|txt)$">
AuthName "Member Only"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/password/.htpasswd
require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

How can I exclude from here the `should_be_excluded.php` from being password protected?
I can change the protection lines if needed, but  I think that something could be done in the regex?

Answer (score 4):

how about something like:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|css|js|php|swf|swz|xml|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|txt)$">
    AuthName "Member Only"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /path/to/password/.htpasswd
    require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
<Files /should_be_excluded.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

this should allow **ALL** access to the excluded file?

Comment: This is not working, did you tried this? if yes and worked what version of apache you have and how do you think what can be the problem?

Comment: @Centurion Try to add `Satisfy all` below `Allow from all`